# Second subdomain redirects to the main domain, but URL remains the same as second domain

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, subdomain

It's quite strange to see this issue as title describes. Here are the details:

1) Created a A-record with "a1". Means subdomain is: `a1.example.com`,

2) created directory by `"sudo nano /var/www/a1.example.com/html/"`

3) Created server block by `"sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/a1.example.com"`

4) Inside the server block, core parts:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/a1.example.com/html;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name a1.example.com

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

5) created the link: `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/a1.example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

6) `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, uncomment: `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`

Make sure: `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` is there

7) restarted nginx: `sudo service nginx restart`

By doing so, the first subdomain, `a1.example.com` works fine.

But when I tried to create the second subdomain, `b2.example.com` following the exact steps above, `b2.example.com` simply does't work: it will redirect to the main page, but the URL remains as `b2.example.com`

what can be wrong?

thank you very much!

---

config for `a1.example.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/a1.example.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name a1.example.com;

    rewrite ^/archives/(\d+)$ http://a1.example.com/?p=$1 permanent;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

    }

}
```

config for `b2.example.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/b2.example.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name b2.example.com;

    rewrite ^/archives/(\d+)$ http://b2.example.com/?p=$1 permanent;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&args;

    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

    }

}
```

---

```
curl -I b2.example.com:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 05:54:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=4r143k0o1m1l62p3g4vt1jrav1; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Link: <http://www.example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://www.example.com/>; rel=shortlink

curl -I a1.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 05:54:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Link: <http://a1.example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
```

Comment: Post the config for both sites, nginx, and the symbolic links you've created.

Comment: Hi Tim, posted the config files for two sites. Both config files are in /etc/nginx/sites-available. and symbolic links created in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

Comment: proxy_pass usually causes the problem you describe, but I don't see it in there. As an aside, this isn't the answer, but why do you have two locations with the same match in each file twice : "location ~ \.php$"?

Comment: Oh, let me remove them. they were just pasted wrongly.

Comment: How / with which tool are you testing? Could you show the output of `curl -I a1.example.com` and `curl -I b1.example.com`?

Comment: updated with the output